# Running multiple nodes automatically using awk from tcl script

Tags: awk, tcl

I have awk file named throughput.awk to calculate throughput from trace files in NS-2.

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[[:space:]]|_"
}

{
  action = $1;
  node_id = $4;
  time = $2;
  dest = $6;
  app = $10;
  pkt_size = $11;

  if ( action == "r" && dest == "MAC" && app == "cbr" && time > 10 && (node_id == 1)) {
    sum_ = sum_ + pkt_size;
  }
}
END {

}
```

what I want is I have to calculate each node's throughput for multiple nodes from TCL script maybe like this :

```
for {set node 1} {$node < N } {incr node}
    exec awk -f throughput.awk test.tr
}
```

so "node" variable inside trace files can be changed from TCL. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use -v parameter:

```
for (node=1;node<N;node++){
    exec awk -v node=$node -f throughput.awk test.tr
}
```

And inside awk

```
if ( action == "r" && dest == "MAC" && app == "cbr" && time > 10 && (node_id == node)) {
    sum_ = sum_ + pkt_size;
  }
```

Before the "=" node will be the name of the variable inside awk and it's value ($node) will be node val in Tcl

Comment: what about node == 1 inside awk file? what should I change then?

Comment: so first "node" before "=" is variable in TCL or awk script? and there is no change inside awk file for node == 1?

Comment: Before the "=" node will be the name of the variable inside awk and it's value ($node) will be node val in TLC

Comment: I got error when running those codes, I use for {set node 1} {$node < 10 } {incr node} { exec awk -v node_id=$node -f throughput.awk test.tr }, and awk file is the same as yours

Comment: It works when I use node=$node and delete node_id declaration in begin of awk file